# Tailwind - Nuxt3 - Mobile display move and zoom

Tags: display, nuxtjs3, tailwind-3

My app can be moved on iPhone mobile. It's not fixed.

Can you help me to find a class to fix the entire mobile display ?

1st picture => [I can move it with fingers, and zoom when I use menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CNgN.png)

2nd picture => [Large movement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecYaR.jpg)

I try width classes without success. I would like to fix the entire display.

Answer (score 0):

An item on your page is overflowing and causing the scrollbar to appear (and therefore the horizontal scrolling).

There are many ways to find out what element is causing it, but the quickest and easiest is to inspect your page with devtools and start deleting blocks one by one and see if the scrolling disappears.

When it does, you start doing the same within that section until you single out what element is causing it and then proceed to find out why and fix it.

You might be tempted to just set the page to overlfow-x: hidden but I highly discourage it: there are a lot of unfortunate consequences you might incur from doing that (you're dealing with the symptom and not the cause).

if you want to disable zoom on mobile devices you should work with a specific meta:

https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-disable-zoom-on-a-mobile-web-page-using-html-and-css.html

However, keep in mind that limiting the user's freedom to interact with the page is almost always a bad idea (and against Googles usability guidelines).

I hope this helps

Comment: Yes there is...

Comment: You can even see it in your own screenshot, at the bottom, dark grey bar https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecYaR.jpg

Comment: Anyway, the problem is your m-4 class on your body, neve ever use margin classes on body. Remove it and the problem vanishes

Comment: True ! Magic ! Thanks very much.

Comment: You're very welcome